# x-editable how to populate the data-pk field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, x-editable

I am using the x-editable plugin to create a table with user's info. I am sending the user ID and trying to put it into the `data-pk` field. I need this so when a user updates the table, I'll know which user to update.

I'm sending the data fine and the table is getting created.

But no matter what I do I can't update the `data-pk` field. Below is the table column:

```
<th data-type="text" data-pk="anything??" data-halign="center" 
data-align="center" data-editable="true" data-resource="post" 
data-field="credit_amount">Credit Amount</th>
```

The data I send is from my Ruby controller and looks like this:

```
def get_customer_data
data_to_return = []
domain = redis.get("domain")
shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: domain)
shop.customers.each do |customer|
  data_to_return.push(
  state: true,
  name: "#{customer.first_name}" + " " + "#{customer.last_name}",
  credit_amount: customer.credit_amount,
  pk: customer.id,
  pending_credit_amount: customer.pending_credit_amount,
  email: customer.email,
  marketing: customer.accepts_marketing,
  enabled: customer.customer_status,
  tags: customer.tags)      
end
render json: data_to_return
```

end

I've tried this jQuery with no luck.

```
$(function(){
$('#credit_amount').editable({
params: function(params) {  //params already contain `name`, `value` and `pk`
  var data = {};
  data['pk'] = params.pk;
  return data;
}
}); 
});
```

I can't even just enter in something static and have it `POST` to my controller. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this took me about a half day to figure out, hopefully this helps someone. But to set the `data-pk` field you need to set an `id` field in the data you send to populate the x-editable table.

I tried maybe 25 combinations to finally get here, but the data I'm sending now looks like this and works like a dream. Notice the `id` field, that's what I was missing before:

```
shop.customers.each do |customer|
  data_to_return.push(
  state: true,
  name: "#{customer.first_name}" + " " + "#{customer.last_name}",
  credit_amount: customer.credit_amount,
  id: customer.id,
  pending_credit_amount: customer.pending_credit_amount,
  email: customer.email,
  marketing: customer.accepts_marketing,
  enabled: customer.customer_status,
  tags: customer.tags)      
end
```